# Is there a way to test web application with lot of dynamic content using JMeter

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing, jmeter-5.0, jmeter-4.0

I am trying to test a web application once I login into the application in the response I see a lot of dynamic content getting loaded like java script files also I could see  a lot of dynamic ids are generated on every run , I tried to handle few token/id using regex but still I see lot of id's on the login response

Is there any other way to test these kind of applications with lot of dynamic values

Any comments/suggestions would be greatly appreciated , thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

With regards to javascript, images, styles, fonts, sounds, etc. - JMeter can handle it automatically, just tick these boxes in the [HTTP Request Defaults](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request_Defaults)

[image]

also add [HTTP Cache Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cache_Manager) to your Test Plan to simulate browser cache.

With regards to handling dynamic IDs - the process is called correlation and there are 3 options:

1. Handle each dynamic parameter manually using [Post-Processors](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors)
2. Use [Correlations Recorder Plugin for JMeter](https://github.com/Blazemeter/CorrelationRecorder) to apply extraction and substitution rules during recording
3. Use [BlazeMeter Proxy Recorder](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-cut-your-jmeter-scripting-time-80) which automatically detects and handles dynamic parameter